# Are some insignificant haram acts unpunished in the hereafter?

Tags: punishment, akhirah

Some haram acts are minor, perhaps for example:

- using someone's stapler without their permission (thereby stealing a staple), or
- using words which are borderline cuss words, like "hell".

I'm wondering if every haram act is punished no matter how minor, or if there's some limitation.

**Question**: Are some insignificant haram acts unpunished in the hereafter?

Clearly, Allah is not inhibited from punishing however He decides is best, and choosing a punishment that suits the act.  However, it seems possible that there's a cut-off point, in order to avoid punishment for things which are ultimately insignificant.

Comment: Well good deeds like reciting duas removes minor sins so if you don't commit any major sin, only commit minor sins and you do stuff like going on Umrah or even just reciting some duas, those minor sins will go away easily. It's mainly the major sins that one is punished for in the hereafter if they don't repent and go to jahannam.